# Como hacer Pequeña rotación de imágenes en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagen, onclick, src

Tengo una pequeña galería, se compone de: una imagen grande, y abajo 4 pequeñas.

Intento hacer lo siguiente:

- Que las imágenes pequeñas, al darle click, se conviertan en la grande:

He pensado este método, pero no es muy bueno:

HTML:

```
<div id="imgGrande">
    <img id="iGrande" src="img/moto1.png" width="100%">
</div>
<div id="imgThumbs">
    <img id="im1" src="img/moto2.png" width="20%">
    <img id="im2" src="img/moto3.png" width="20%">
    <img id="im3" src="img/moto4.jpg" width="20%">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#im1").on("click", function(){
    $("#iGrande").attr("src", "img/moto2.png");
    $("#im1").attr("src", "img/moto1.png");
});
```

Creo que el método me parece un poco "cutre", entonces quiero buscar alguna recomendación mejor.

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que opinas de esto

```
<script>
//CREAMOS FUNCION DE CLICK EN CADA IMAGEN
$("#imgThumbs img").on("click", function(){
    var srcG=$("#iGrande").attr("src"); //GUARDO LA IMAGEN GRANDE
    var src=$(this).attr("src"); //GUARDO LA IMAGEN PEQUEÑA
    $("#iGrande").fadeOut("slow",function(){ //DESAPAREZCO LA IMAGEN GRANDE
        $(this).attr("src", src).fadeIn("slow"); //ASIGNO LA NUEVA IMG AL SRC Y LA MUESTRO
    })
    $(this).attr("src", srcG); //AGREGO LA IMG GRANDE EN LA PEQUEÑA QUE SE DIO CLICK
});
</script>
```

Saludos :)

Comment: Siempre debe ir una explicación, no solo el código te sugiero revisar [answer]

Comment: Que opinas @AlfredoPaz, esto seria mas correcto?. Aunque como es una pregunta muy especifica no lo creí necesario :)

Comment: Me encanta! Esto es lo que necesitaba! Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Genial @JavierAvilaFernandez mucho exito!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar clases en lugar de ids, de ese modo solo necesitarias un handler.  Algo asi:

```js
$(".im").on("click", function(){        
    $("#iGrande").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgGrande">
    <img id="iGrande" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" width="40%">
</div>
<div id="imgThumbs">
    <img class="im" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" width="20%">
    <img class="im" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=20" width="20%">
    <img class="im" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=30" width="20%">
</div>
```